# Change Django alphabetical ordering to custom ordering

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I've created a model `Reservation` and my code(`models.py`) looks something like this:

```
#Choices
STATUS_CHOICES = ( ('APPROVED','Approved'),('PENDING', 'Pending'), ('CANCELED', 'Canceled') )

# Reservation model
class Reservation(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-status']

    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='PENDING', max_length=25)
```

I want to order my reservations like this:

1. Pending
2. Approved
3. Canceled

But my current order is:

1. Pending
2. Canceled
3. Approved

It looks like Django is ordering my objects alphabetically.

**How can I change the alphabetical order to the one described above?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change status to an `IntegerField`, and define constants for the three states. Then sorting by 'status' should do what you want.

```
PENDING = 1
APPROVED = 2
CANCELED = 3

STATUS_CHOICES = (APPROVED,'Approved'),(PENDING, 'Pending'), (CANCELED, 'Canceled))
```

Or you could create a `StatusChoice` model, with a field `sort_order`. Make `Reservation.status` a foreign key to the new model, and sort by `status__sort_order`.

Another option would be to sort in SQL by using the `order_by` parameter in [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra).